# Error when using foreach to get transform's parent/child GameObjects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get the children of the transform's parent, but I can't seem to figure it out and I can't seem to find anything online about it.

```
foreach (GameObject col in transform.parent)
{
    print("what");
}
```

That just gives me the error:

> Cannot cast from source type to destination type

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

[`transform.parent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-parent.html) is a property and a type of `Transform` not `GameObject`. Replace `GameObject` with `Transform`.

Below is what it should look like:

```
foreach (Transform col in transform.parent)
{
    print("what" + col.name);
}
```